# C++ CreateProcess output to wstring

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess, wstring

I have this code that is being used for executing CMD commands and storing the output to a string:

```
string run(char *command){
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr, &sa, 0) ) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ){
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0) ) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ){
        exit(1);
    }
    char *szCmdline=command;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    bool bSuccess = FALSE;
    ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
    ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        szCmdline,     // command line
        NULL,          // process security attributes
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,             // creation flags
        NULL,          // use parent's environment
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    if ( ! bSuccess ) {

        exit(1);
    }
    DWORD dwRead;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    bool bSuccess2 = FALSE;
    std::string out = "", err = "";
    for (;;) {
        bSuccess2=ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess2 || dwRead == 0 ) break;

        std::string s(chBuf, dwRead);
        out += s;
    }
    dwRead = 0;
    for (;;) {
        bSuccess2=ReadFile( g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess2 || dwRead == 0 ) break;

        std::string s(chBuf, dwRead);
        err += s;
    }

    return out;
}
```

What I want, is to store the output as **w**string. I tried achieving that by doing this:

```
wstring run(char *command){
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, &g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr, &sa, 0) ) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ){
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &sa, 0) ) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) ){
        exit(1);
    }
    char *szCmdline=command;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    bool bSuccess = FALSE;
    ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
    ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        szCmdline,     // command line
        NULL,          // process security attributes
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,             // creation flags
        NULL,          // use parent's environment
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_ERR_Wr);
    CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);
    if ( ! bSuccess ) {

        exit(1);
    }
    DWORD dwRead;
    wchar_t chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    bool bSuccess2 = FALSE;
    std::wstring out = L"", err = L"";
    for (;;) {
        bSuccess2=ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess2 || dwRead == 0 ) break;

        std::wstring s(chBuf, dwRead);
        out += s;
    }
    dwRead = 0;
    for (;;) {
        bSuccess2=ReadFile( g_hChildStd_ERR_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if( ! bSuccess2 || dwRead == 0 ) break;

        std::wstring s(chBuf, dwRead);
        err += s;
    }

    return out;
}
```

But everytime I try it, the string "out" does not contain anything. Can anyone point me in a correct direction? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Step 1, do some debugging

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for the comment! Yeah, did that. Looks like it breaks from the for loop on "if( ! bSuccess2 || dwRead == 0 ) break;" So for some reason the output cannot be read at all (and thus stored in the wstring)

Comment: Step 2, keep debugging. The code breaks out of the for loop. Why? What is `bSuccess2`? What is `dwRead`? If `bSuccess2` indicates an error, call `GetLastError` as is documented. You need to spend some time debugging. You have given up far too soon.

Comment: I haven't given up. I will keep debuging. Just wanted to see if anyone sees something that I'm doing wrong from their perspective.
I found out that the line where the for loop breaks gives a broken pipe error.

Comment: It's a bit rude to ask the question before you've debugged properly. We aren't a debugging service. You are expected to work on your problem until you have exhausted such basic debugging tasks, before asking.

Comment: Okay seems like the process is successfully started, the output is written to the wchar_t but the problem arises when trying to put the data from wchar_t to the wstring

Comment: @MrWhite - *problem arises when trying to put the data from wchar_t to the wstring* - from the fact that you change the declared type of the buffer - the type of its contents does not change. use `wchar_t chBuf[BUFSIZE];` as buffer for `ReadFile` is error by sense. anyway it content will be mutibyte-string with `GetConsoleOutputCP` encoding. so you need declare buffer as `char` and covert it to `wchar_t` via `MultiByteToWideChar(GetConsoleOutputCP(), 0, chBuf, dwRead,..)`

Comment: @RbMm works perfectly, thank you very much for your help! :)